# Python - requests is prefixing extra characters in the output

Tags: python, json, python-requests, gerrit

I am using `requests` module to run a curl command, not sure why its prefixing `')]}\'` in the front of the output, it makes `r.json()` fail as shown below.

When I paste the URL in a browser and execute, it downloads a .json file, and that file has same characters in the front, Am I missing some option? I need to process the output as json.

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://gerrit-review-server/a/changes/?q=status:open%20project:myproj/test/a_proj%20change:1510&o=CURRENT_REVISION', verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','pass'), 
>>> 

>>> r.text
')]}\'\n[{"id":"myproj%2Ftest%2Fa_proj~master~I15790ba05690e0a9984cb05bce06574645274966","project":"myproj/test/a_proj","branch":"master","hashtags":[],"change_id":"I15790ba05690e0a9984cb05bce06574645274966","subject":"Test","status":"NEW","created":"2021-01-27 19:38:57.000000000","updated":"2021-03-21 14:19:42.000000000","submit_type":"MERGE_IF_NECESSARY","mergeable":true,"insertions":1,"deletions":0,"total_comment_count":0,"unresolved_comment_count":0,"has_review_started":true,"_number":1510,"owner":{"_account_id":10008339},"current_revision":"fe3cc60cc66ad6f20c631ee818ccd91955c69d37",<..deleted..>,"description":"Rebase"}},"requirements":[]}]\n'

>>> r.json()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>>>
```

Comment: It's possible that the other end is sending malformed JSON.

Comment: possible, I see those characters even when I run it as plain curl command from my linux shell, is there an workaround to handle it using python? thanks.

Comment: If it's consistent, you could do `chopped = req.text[5:]` to drop the first 5 characters, then just do `from json import loads; loads(chopped)` to decode it using the Python library instead of through `requests`. If it's inconsistent, you may be able to do `req.text.split("\n")[1]` to drop the first part as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000206/carcigenicate) says, it seems that the json is wrongly formatted. You can try the loads, and if it fails try to correct it:

```
r = requests.get(some_url) 

try:
    data = r.json()
except json.JSONDecodeError:
    # cut everything in front of the first "\n" 
    raw_data = r.text.split("\n", maxsplit=1)[1]
    # cut everything behind the last "\n"
    raw_data = raw_data.rsplit("\n", maxsplit=1)[0]
    # try to load again the json
    # If it fails it will raise the exception again
    data = json.loads(raw_data)
```